# Initialize a generic type object with another generic interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was to provide type safety to a React context.

I have an interface like this

```
interface Form<T> {
  inputTracker: (val: { name: string; value: T }) => void;
  errorTracker: (val: { name: string }) => boolean;
}
```

This is the interface for Context. I left it generic so that wherever I use it, I can input custom types for the form.

Now I want to initialize a context with this interface but I am having a hard time.

```
export const FormContext: Form<T> = createContext<Form<T>>({
  inputTracker: (val) => {},
  errorTracker: (val) => true,
});
```

I cant seem to find a way to give another generic variable to FormContext type so that I can pass to to `Form`.
I need this type of interface because I want to use this context in many place like this.

```
const {inputTracker} = useContext<CustomType>(FormContext);
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: How about just use `useContext<Form<T>>(FormContext`, and declare `createContext<Form<any>>` Is it work wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understood what you are asking. Is this what you are looking for?

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-hill-sux7n?file=/src/App.tsx:0-531)

```
import React from "react";

interface Form<T> {
  inputTracker: (val: { name: string; value: T }) => void;
  errorTracker: (val: { name: string }) => boolean;
}

export const FormContext = React.createContext<Form<number>>({
  inputTracker: (value: { name: string; value: number }) => {},
  errorTracker: (value: { name: string }) => true
});

const App: React.FC = () => {

  const formContext = React.useContext(FormContext);
  const { inputTracker, errorTracker } = formContext;

  return <div>App</div>;
};

export default App;
```